# How to change language in web page using Selenium(Java)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is their a way to pre-define a language for webpage? I want to load google page in Spanish, can we set property of webdriver in such a way that it load the page in Spanish.

Comment: What the URL you are using? I think you can just use this URL: https://www.google.es/

Comment: Can i set the browser property to load pages in particular language..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [**this**](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks) link:

For Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( "intl.accept_languages", "es" ); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

For Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```