# How to configure webpage language using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanna set the web page language to international languages (eg: es i.e spanish) , I tried below code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
driver.close();
```

The above code is successfully translating only google.
Coming to other websites like yahoo, the page is remained in english and the chrome browser is translated in spanish. I want to translate entire webpage as well.
Can anyone help me out please.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the below link where the answer was already given - [Change web page language with webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788425/how-to-change-language-in-web-page-using-seleniumjava)

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. That even implements the same code what i have done. I want to translate the entire web page in other language. is this possible through selenium ?

Comment: Changing the chrome option , is only changing the browser language. To be clear , the chrome button what we use for new tab,new window etc etc... all those language are changing but not text on the web page(content on webpage) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Maybe it would clear up things: [How to change language on desired browser](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities).

Another useful tool is [i18n-checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) (to check is your language supported).

Comment: Above mentioned links are not working.  I want to translate the entire webpage in other language. can this be done using selenium ? Changing the chrome option , is only changing the browser language. To be clear , the chrome button what we use for new tab,new window etc etc... all those language are changing but not text on the web page(content on webpage) .